# How do I fetch a scrapy.http.request.Request?

Tags: python, scrapy

**Note:** I've gone through the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), I'd just like to know how fetch works.

With scrapy shell, this code works well.

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
>>> def parse(response):
...     print('parse %s' % response)
... 
>>> req = scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=parse)
>>> fetch(req)
```

Which gets me

```
2020-07-03 05:21:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-07-03 05:21:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/> (referer: None)
parse <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
```

How do I run it in a .py file?

I put the code in `fetch_req.py` file and run the file with this command

```
python fetch_req.py
```

then I got

> NameError: name 'fetch' is not defined

I understood this, as `fetch` is a method of `scrapy.shell.Shell instance`, so I added this to `fetch_req.py`.

```
from scrapy import shell
shell.Shell.fetch(req)
```

then I got

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-914d5e1bbfe3> in <module>()
----> 1 shell.Shell.fetch(req)

TypeError: fetch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request_or_url'
```

I [googled the error](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ALeKk01VOB5FZ2DY3UTL9ox8FictQLdqeg%3A1593725966142&ei=DlT-XuigCI36-gT164TADQ&q=%22fetch%28%29%20missing%201%20required%20positional%20argument%22&oq=%22fetch%28%29%20missing%201%20required%20positional%20argument%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQzQI6BwgjEK4CECdQ1T9Y1T9g6EFoAHAAeACAAYcCiAGEBJIBAzItMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjo39Lww6_qAhUNvZ4KHfU1AdgQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) but got no hit. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should really complete the Scrapy tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `yield` the request so that scrapy engine puts into it's queue and executes the request.

To do understand this better you should follow @Gallaecio suggestion and follow scrapy's [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). It's pretty straightforward.

**EDIT**

I understand now what you mean, however I don't understand why you want to use scrapy in this way. Surely `fetch` method wasn't desgined for this.

Anyhow the problem is that you are calling fetch as if it was a staticmethod.

```
from scrapy import shell
shell.Shell.fetch(req)
```

You should instantiate the object and then call the method from the object. The missing required argument is raised because it expects `self` and `request_or_url` as arguments.

You can also try passing the class as the first argument. (As if it was a classmethod)

Those will likely lead to new exceptions though.

Comment: Thank you. I've gone through the tutorial, I'd just like to know how fetch works. Did you notice what I said at the beginning? without `yield`, `fetch(req)` works well in scrapy shell.

Comment: @JJJohn sorry, my bad. I read your question more thoroughly and edited my answer. Hope it helps.